# Intercept private methods inside CDI beans

Tags: jsf, cdi, interceptor

I have a CDI bean with private method inside it. I have written an interceptor like following:

Interceptor's code:

```
@Interceptor
@TimeMeasure
public class TimeWatcher implements Serializable {

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object logMethodEntry(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {

        long t0 = System.nanoTime();
        try {
            return ctx.proceed();
        } finally {
            long dt = System.nanoTime() - t0;
            System.out.println("Method execution time: " + ctx.getMethod().getName() +  " - " + dt);
        }
    }
}
```

Annotation's code:

```
 import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
    import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;
    import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;


    @InterceptorBinding
    @Target({TYPE, METHOD})
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    public @interface TimeMeasure {

    }
```

Everything works fine only for public methods which are called externally, if I call method from inside CDI bean it doesn't work. I use JSF 2.0 MyFaces together with Omnifaces to accomplish @ViewScoped

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is by design.  Internal calls can never be intercepted.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please say where do you know it from? I didn't find it mentioned in Oracle manual. Do I have to read specs to know such nuances?

Comment: I don't have a spec/reference for that, but with CDI you can only intercept life-cycle and business methods, i.e., external calls to your CDI bean.  Interceptors are often implemented by dynamic proxies (decorator pattern) -- internal calls can therefore usually not be intercepted.  This should/may also fail for public methods that are called from within your bean (but may be implementation dependent...).  Regarding such "nuances", just remember that all the fancy stuff (transactions, locking, interceptors) for CDI/EJB beans only works for external calls.